# Disable USB Storage Devices in El Capitan

Tags: macos, command-line, usb, kernel-extensions

The company I work for is required to disable the ability to connect USB mass storage devices on all production computers. All computers run OS X 10.11.6. Every computer has the following setup:

1. USB ports on the machine itself
2. USB over Ethernet that is then connected to a USB Hub (for long distance lines)

I've done the following to try to disable USB devices:

1. I've booted into Recovery Mode and run `csrutil disable`
2. Then I booted into my admin account and ran:

```bsh
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext/
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageDriver.kext/

sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageDriver.kext /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageDriver.kextbu
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kextbu

sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions
```

3. Emptied my Trash
4. Rebooted
5. Reenabled `csrutil`

And for some odd reason USB mass storage devices still work on all ports.
I triple checked that the kernel extensions have been renamed properly. This method has worked in disabling WiFi and Bluetooth so far, but the USBs still work.

I do not wish to disable the USB ports completely - only USB storage devices.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337114/how-to-block-unlock-usb-port-in-mac-os-x-programatically-without-reboot

Comment: @SteveChambers Thanks for the suggestion. No, I have not soon this answer yet. Howerer, Apple's Workgroup Manager unfortunately does not work with El Capitan.